# Get the current post category slug in wordpress custom post type query

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to get the current post category slug from the custom post type
in the shortcode function but it is not working where I am mistaking? Here is my complete code. It is not getting the `<?php echo $slug; ?>`

```
<?php
            $mi_args = array(
            'post_status'    => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => '99999',
            'post_type'      => 'blog'
            );
            $mi_query = new WP_Query($mi_args);
            if($mi_query->have_posts()):
            while ($mi_query->have_posts()): $mi_query->the_post();
            $portfolio_url = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'portfolio_url_portfolio-url', true );
            $hover_color = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'hove_color_hover-color', true );
            // Getting the category slug
               
$categories = get_the_category(get_the_ID());
        foreach ($categories as $category){ 
            $slug = $category->slug;
?>
            <?php echo $slug; ?>
<div class="grid-item" data-filter="<?php echo $slug; ?>"></div>
<?php
        }
            ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: when you say "it is not working", you mean it's not filling the data-attribute `data-filter`?

Comment: Yes t's not filling the data-attribute data-filter.

Comment: if you `print_r($categories);` right before the `foreach`, what's the output?

Comment: It is showing blank array

Comment: I am using this code in a shortcode function in function.php

Comment: in regards to `get_the_category`, I'm reading `Note: This function only returns results from the default "category" taxonomy`. If you are using a custom taxonomy, you should use a different function, like `get_the_terms()` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/

Comment: YEs get_the_terms works thank you

Comment: Why did you accept the answer? It doesn't appear to be relevant

Comment: there also the code ``` $work_category = get_the_terms( the_post()->ID, 'taxonomy' );```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

get_the_category(get_the_ID());

```
            <?php
              $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'work',
                'posts_per_page' => '9'
              );
              $work_loop = new WP_Query( $args );
              if ( $work_loop->have_posts() ) :
                while ( $work_loop->have_posts() ) : $work_loop->the_post();
                  // Set variables
                    $cat_ids                = get_the_ID();
                    $cat_names_array        = get_the_category($ids);
                    $work_category           = get_the_category( get_the_ID() );
                    $work_title             = get_field( 'work_title' );
                    $work_main_image        = get_field( 'work_main_image' );
                    $work_link              = get_field( 'work_title' );
                    $work_about             = get_field( 'work_about' );
                    // $work_category = get_the_terms( the_post()->ID, 'taxonomy' );
                  // Output
                  ?>
                  <a href="<?php echo $work_main_image['url']; ?>" class="single_item link <?php foreach ( $work_category as $key => $value) { echo $value->category_nicename . " "; } ?> col-md-4 col-sm-6 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.3s">
                    <img src="<?php echo $work_main_image['url']; ?>" alt=""> 
                </a>
                <?php
                  endwhile;
                wp_reset_postdata();
              endif; 
            ?>
```

Comment: what is this? this not OP's code

Comment: Your code is not working did you checked?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).